# Water softener plumbing

Tags: plumbing, water

I am getting ready to put in a softener - my house never had one previously.

Attached is a photo of my plumbing setup. I have an irrigation system that I assume I want to bypass for softened water since that could kill my grass.

Based on this photo, do I need to put in a softener loop to prevent softened water from going outside? [image: plumbing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in not wanting to water your lawn with softened water. I don't know that it would kill your lawn, but you'd waste *huge* amounts of salt softening water for your lawn, and that's totally unnecessary.

I'm not 100% certain what you mean by a "softener loop", but to install your softener, you'll need to:

- Shut off your cold water supply valve.
- Cut the pipe leading from it (leave several inches for comfortable working)
- Add plumbing to bring the water to wherever you will place the softener.
- Install a shut-off valve and a softener by-pass with shut off valve.

  - Should the softener ever fail, leak, or need to be removed for any reason, this will allow you to shut off water to the softener and open the bypass valve allowing you to continue to have water in the house for the whole time the softener is out of service.
- Add the appropriate fittings to attach to your softener
- Add plumbing to the output side of the softener and a shutoff valve, then plumb to meet up with the softener bypass
- Add plumbing to continue back to the existing cold water plumbing

Of note:

- Generally all water going to the house is softened, both hot and cold. It's up to you if you only want to soften the cold drinking water, but cook, bathe, wash dishes & laundry with hard water, but you'll loose a lot of the benefits of having the softener

  - I say this because you've labeled the pipe "Cold H2O". If that's actually just the main feed to the rest of the house, including the water heater, then never mind. ;)

---

**Unrelated side note**

There is a blue electrical junction box in your picture without a cover. The NEC requires that this box have a cover on it. I don't know if it's been temporarily removed for some ongoing work or if it's been this way for a while, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: That "cold H2O" is the pipe that goes into the water heater. Sorry if that was unclear. And yes, I removed the cover on the box because I am wiring up an outlet for the water softener.

Comment: Fair enough, @Ben, you can ignore the two "notes" then.

Comment: A water softener loop is a mechanism that prevents the softened water from going to the outside systems. Some houses were designed with these in mind for future water softener installations. Based on what you are describing, I think I need to create that bypass loop myself since there appears to be nothing like that in my house.

Comment: Gotcha. I happen to live in a house built in the 1890s, so there wasn't much in the way of "extras" built in.

Comment: Haha! Yeah, they probably didn't have such luxuries in mind in mind back then :)